# RuntimeError: Event loop is closed Discord Bot

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, python-asyncio

I am trying to make a bot that will download a song from YouTube and then play it. I have been able to set up the search and download function, but for some reason my bot crashes after downloading the YouTube song. From what I can gather, it is something to do with the Asyncio.

EDIT: Added full output as well as entire code below, the relevant part of the code should still be the <play part, but I have attached the rest.

```
The error I get:


C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProjects\BattleBot\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/Admin/PycharmProjects/BattleBot/main.py
The final bot has started.
[youtube] vOXZkm9p_zY: Downloading webpage
[youtube] vOXZkm9p_zY: Downloading player 68cc98b3
WARNING: Requested formats are incompatible for merge and will be merged into mkv.
[download] Destination: Imagine Dragons - Birds (Animated Video)-vOXZkm9p_zY.f137.mp4
[download] 100% of 66.34MiB in 00:03                          
[download] Destination: Imagine Dragons - Birds (Animated Video)-vOXZkm9p_zY.f251.webm
[download] 100% of 3.56MiB in 00:00                          
[ffmpeg] Merging formats into "Imagine Dragons - Birds (Animated Video)-vOXZkm9p_zY.mkv"
Deleting original file Imagine Dragons - Birds (Animated Video)-vOXZkm9p_zY.f137.mp4 (pass -k to keep)
Deleting original file Imagine Dragons - Birds (Animated Video)-vOXZkm9p_zY.f251.webm (pass -k to keep)
Exception ignored in: <function _ProactorBasePipeTransport.__del__ at 0x000001CBE9576F70>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 116, in __del__
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 108, in close
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 746, in call_soon
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 510, in _check_closed
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
_ClientEventTask exception was never retrieved
future: <ClientEventTask state=finished event=on_message coro=<function on_message at 0x000001CB83D05AF0> exception=SystemExit(0)>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProjects\BattleBot\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 713, in run
    loop.run_forever()
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\windows_events.py", line 316, in run_forever
    super().run_forever()
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 596, in run_forever
    self._run_once()
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 1890, in _run_once
    handle._run()
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\events.py", line 80, in _run
    self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProjects\BattleBot\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProjects\BattleBot\main.py", line 31, in on_message
    youtube_dl.main(opts)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProjects\BattleBot\venv\lib\site-packages\youtube_dl\__init__.py", line 475, in main
    _real_main(argv)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProjects\BattleBot\venv\lib\site-packages\youtube_dl\__init__.py", line 470, in _real_main
    sys.exit(retcode)
SystemExit: 0

Process finished with exit code 0
```

The code:

```
import os
import discord
import youtube_dl
from youtube_api import YouTubeDataAPI

intents = discord.Intents().all()
activity = discord.Activity(name='Tests', type=discord.ActivityType.watching)
bot = discord.Client(intents=intents, activity=activity)
yt = YouTubeDataAPI("")
link = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v="
os.chdir('C:/Songs')
searchSong = ""


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("The final bot has started.")


@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    search_song = str(message.content)
    if search_song.startswith('<play'):
        search_song = search_song[6:]
        searches = yt.search(q=search_song, max_results=1)
        valuesColl = searches[0].values()
        valueIter = iter(valuesColl)
        songID = next(valueIter)

        opts = [(link + songID)]
        youtube_dl.main(opts)
        files = [x for x in os.listdir('C:\\Songs') if x.endswith(".mp4")]
        newest = max(files, key=os.path.getctime)
        channel = message.channel
        voice_channel = message.author.voice.channel
        vc = await voice_channel.connect()
        vc.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(newest))


@bot.event
async def on_member_update(before, after):
    if before.status != after.status and (str(after.status) == "idle" or str(after.status) == "offline") and str(
            before.status) != "offline":
        if after.voice is not None:
            embed = discord.Embed(title=f"KICKED FOR BEING " + str(after.status))
            embed.add_field(name='Test Kick', value=before.mention)
            embed.add_field(name='AMM', value="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w1PRiHEHJd8")
            channel = bot.get_channel(788477061962268693)
            await channel.send(embed=embed)
            await after.edit(voice_channel=None)


@bot.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member, before, after):
    if before.channel is None and after.channel is not None and str(member.status) == "offline":
        embed = discord.Embed(title=f"KICKED FOR BEING " + str(member.status))
        embed.add_field(name='Test Kick', value=member.mention)
        embed.add_field(name='AMM', value="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w1PRiHEHJd8")
        channel = bot.get_channel(channelid)
        await channel.send(embed=embed)
        await member.edit(voice_channel=None)
```

Comment: Is that a complete traceback? Can you add more code? 
Neither the traceback nor your code show which line in the code caused the chain of exceptions.

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59255332/exception-event-loop-is-closed-with-aiohttp-and-asyncio-in-python-3-8

Comment: Added the full output as well as all the code, thank you.